# What's the meaning of "<mce:script type="text/javascript"><!-- --></mce:script>"

Tags: dojo, tinymce

In the demo codes of dojo 1.6, I found some code like the below:

```
<mce:script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//other codes
-->
</mce:script>
```

So, what's the meaning of this kind of codes?
And what are the differences between these codes and

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script >?
```

Comment: The `mce:script` is generated by TinyMCE (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com). Can you paste the link of the demo? Not sure why TinyMCE is included in a dojo demo.

Comment: I have checked the internet and most answers said as your words - "generated by TinyMCE". The link is "http://blog.csdn.net/dojotoolkit/article/details/6526897" the fifth code block. Thx so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you can read Chinese. me too :-)

If you open the demo page ( http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/events/demo/query.html ) in browser and view its source code, you can see there is no `mce:script` tags, just `script` tag. So the reason is caused by the blog publishing system, when the author paste the JavaScript code to it, it automatically replace the `script` tag with `mce:script` tag to avoid XSS attack.

Comment: Seems that you are chengfu_Alex :) followed you in sina weibo.

I got it, maybe their pulishing system contains this TingMCE. Thanks so much.